# Verify JWT with RS256 (asymmetric) in C#

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa, public-key

I have some code like this which I believe is failing because it's using an Asymmetric RS256 but has "SymmetricSecurityKey()".  The tokens were hand generated from https://jwt.io/

1. How do I convert this to use my Asymmetric public key?
2. Also, I'm new to C# and I'd like to target dotnet standard, so I'm also wondering if I'm using the wrong libs?  (I'm depending on the preview release)

```
λ cat Program.cs
﻿using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace jwttest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA";
            var pubKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSvvkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHcaT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIytvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWbV6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9MwIDAQAB";
            var rawKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pubKey);

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            // var rsa = ?
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, new TokenValidationParameters {
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(rawKey)
            },
            out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        }
    }
}

C:\src\jwttest (cgt-test-5 -> origin)
λ dotnet run
[2020-08-18T23:41:05.7108585-07:00 Info] raw=System.Byte[] [392]
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at jwttest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\jwttest\Program.cs:line 22

λ cat jwttest.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Using preview release because it only depends on dotnet standard.  Prior versions need framework. -->
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.7.2-preview-10803222715" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

λ cat jwt.json
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403823/verifying-jwt-signed-with-the-rs256-algorithm-using-public-key-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Regarding your 1st question:
  According to your posted stack trace, you seem to be using .NET Core 3.1. This allows you to easily import your public X.509/SPKI key as follows:

  ```
  var pubKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSvvkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHcaT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIytvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWbV6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9MwIDAQAB";

  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(pubKey), out _); // import the public X.509/SPKI DER encoded key
  ```

  [`ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.1) is available since .NET Core 3.0.

  **Edit** start:
  In earlier versions of .NET Core (before 3.0) or in the .NET Framework [`ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.1) is not available, so at least [.NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is required.

  For earlier versions, e.g. .NET Standard 2.0, one possibility is to use [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/), more precisely its `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader` class, which allows the import of public keys in X509/SPKI format (and, irrelevant for you, also in PKCS#1 format). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204020/9014097) you will find an example of how to use `PemReader`. `PemReader` processes, as the name suggests, a PEM encoding, i.e. the conversion to a DER encoding (i.e. the removal of header, footer and line breaks, as well as the Base64 decoding of the remainder) as required by `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` *must not be done*. Also note that `PemReader` expects at least one line break immediately after the header (`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n`) and a second one immediately before the footer (`\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`), the line breaks in the Base64 encoded body after every 64 characters are optional for `PemReader`.

  Another possibility is the package [opensslkey](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opensslkey) providing the method `opensslkey.DecodeX509PublicKey()`, which can process an X509/SPKI key in DER encoding analogous to `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`. **Edit** end
- Regarding your 2nd question:
  There are several [.NET standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) versions, e.g. .NET Core 3.0 implements .NET Standard 2.1. The package *System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt [6.7.2-preview-10803222715](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/6.7.2-preview-10803222715)* you are using requires .NET Standard 2.0.

  `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` is a package that supports the creation and validation of JSON Web Tokens (JWT). In the case of the posted token, the validation could be implemented as follows:

  ```
  string jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA";

  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  bool verified = false;
  try
  {
      tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateAudience = false,                       
          ValidateLifetime = false,
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
      },
      out _);

      verified = true;
  }
  catch 
  {
      verified = false;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Verified: " + verified);
  ```

  The validation can be controlled via the validation parameters, i.e. via the 2nd parameter of [`ValidateToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=azure-dotnet). Since the posted token does not contain the [claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) *iss*, *aud* and *exp* (this can be verified e.g. on https://jwt.io/), they are excluded from the validation in my example.

  In the tutorial [*Creating And Validating JWT Tokens In ASP.NET Core*](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/15/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/) you will find a more detailed explanation, especially in the chapter *Validating A Token*.

  `ValidateToken()` essentially encapsulates the verification process of the JWT signature. A [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) is a data structure that consists of three parts: header, payload and signature, the individual parts being Base64url encoded and separated from each other by a dot.
  The signature is created using various algorithms, e.g. in your case [*RS256*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.3), which means that the data (Base64url encoded header and payload including separator) is signed using the algorithm RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and digest SHA256.
  The verification of a token corresponds to the verification of the signature, which can also be done solely with cryptographic APIs (i.e. without participation of *System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt*), as it is done in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34423434/9014097) of the linked question in the comment of @zaitsman.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You're a life saver --I've been tearing my hair out trying to follow the ms docs only to find that I've used the wrong flavor of dotnet.  This is for a library that I want to work with older code that's built on dotnet framework, and newer code built on dotnet core 3.1. I find it very odd that RSACryptoServiceProvider() doesn't take a string and automatically detect and covert the pki key.

Comment: Woops, one problem is this part doesn't work if I target dotnetstandard2.0, but does with dotnetstandard2.1

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(pubKey), out _); // import the public X.509/SPKI DER encoded key
```

Comment: For earlier versions than .NET Standard 2.1 `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo` is not available, here another option is needed, see the Edit-section of my first point.