# JWT Validation in .Net Core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, rs256

I've been struggling with this for a few days...  There seems to be a number of similar questions on here but I can't find one which covers this exact scenario.

I have a node service which is creating a jsonwebtoken NPM package (RS256).  Any other node service is able to validate the token as supplied by the UI and read the claims  _ can also validate on jwt.io.

However I need to add a .net core api to the solution and I can't simply can't get it work - I feel like I have tried a million different combinations of setting up the api middleware, but there is clearly something I am missing and I can't find any documentation for the right way of doing this - obviously I also want to read the claims, but right now, before I pull my hair out, I just want to validate the token and hit a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure `JWT` bearer authentication (as well as the [token validation options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.tokenvalidationparameters)) on `DI` using [AddJwtBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer) extension method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` `NuGet` package:

```
// The below code used to be in Startup.ConfigureServices method 
// before the minimal API with all stuff in Program.cs file has been introduced 

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false, 
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ... = ,
        };
        options.Authority = <settings-your-authority>;
        options. ect..
    });

...

// Use configured JWT auth (used to be in Startup.Configure method) 

var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
...
app.Run();
```

And see here how to [Verify JWT with RS256 (asymmetric) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481513/verify-jwt-with-rs256-asymmetric-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Many thanks - in the end once I had done this I needed to change the encryption method of the token created by the node service.