# How to encrypt a message with Private Key and decrypt it elsewhere with only the Public Key

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, .net-4.8

Lets say, Person1 has two files: **person1.public.key** and **person1.private.key**. This person uses his person1.private.key to encrypt a message and send it to me.

I only have the file person1.public.key, and I want to decrypt the message sent to me.

How to:

- encrypt the message on Person1's side?
- decrypt the message on my side?

I did search online, but all examples I saw was the code generating the keys on runtime. I want to use the keys in the files.

Comment: If they are the receiver, you encrypt using their public key and they decrypt with their private key. If you are the receiver, you need your own private key and they use your public key. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: Not necessarily. Using your private key to encrypt a message so the others can decrypt it with your public key is also a valid method. This is how Bitcoin works, for example.

Comment: This article says otherwise? https://bitzuma.com/posts/six-things-bitcoin-users-should-know-about-private-keys/

Comment: "Transactions are Messages Signed with a Private Key. [...] Anyone with a signature and public key can easily authenticate a message."

Comment: Right, but that's signing not encryption? I'd update your question to ask about signing.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is a lot I still need to learn about RSA. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [RSA.ImportFromPem(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-6.0)?

It supports the following PEM labels:

- PUBLIC KEY
- PRIVATE KEY
- RSA PRIVATE KEY
- RSA PUBLIC KEY

```c#
var keyString = loadFileIntoReadyOnlySpan();
var rsaKey = RSA.Create();
rsaKey.ImportFromPem(keyString);
```

I assume you know/can figure out how to load a file

Comment: This looks to be a solution, but I forgot to say that I'm using .Net Framework 4.8. There is any similar method available on 4.8?

Comment: @WolfgangAmadeus - For DER or PEM encoded keys on .NET Framework 4.8 it is most convenient to use BouncyCastle, s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204020/9014097)